# Highlight non-local variables in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

In js2-mode, global variables are automatically highlighted for me:

[image]

How can I do the same in Emacs lisp? I'd like to be able to highlight `flymake-log-level` and `barr` in the following:

```
(defun foo ()
  (let (bar baz)
    (setq baz flymake-log-level) ;; flymake-log-level isn't locally bound
    (setq barr (1+ flymake-log-level)))) ;; misspelled bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to take advantage of the byte-compiler by installing [flycheck](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck). Flycheck is an alternative to flymake and has support for Elisp.

It won't help you for the first example, but it will for the second (assuming the necessary `require` is present):

```
(require 'flymake)

(defun foo ()
  (let (bar baz)
    (setq baz flymake-log-level) ;; no complaints here
    (setq barr (1+ flymake-log-level)))) ;; assignment to free variable `barr'
```

There's also [hl-defined.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hl-defined.el), a minor mode that does almost exactly what is described in the question. Install it, then run `hdefd-highlight-mode` in an emacs-lisp-mode buffer. You can then run the command `hdefd-cycle` until you are only showing variables that aren't already defined. This gives something like:

[image: hl-defined screenshot]

(This isn't perfect, hl-defined doesn't recognise that `fn` is a parameter not a free variable, and it confuses the function `list` with the parameter used here. Still, it's very helpful for the use case described in the question.)

Finally, some packages include highlighting for the functions they define. For example, [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) provides highlighting for its functions, plus the variable names it uses in anaphoric macros (i.e it highlights `it`).

```
;; Enable syntax highlighting of dash functions
(eval-after-load "dash" '(dash-enable-font-lock))
```

Comment: Thank you for using my project :)  A little correction though:  Flycheck is no fork of Flymake.  Initially it built upon its API, but nowadays it is an independent clean-room implementation of on-the-fly syntax checking.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this is quite a bit of work...

The best way is to use `font-lock-mode` and add a new rule. Normally, rules contains a regexp to match something, however, it is also legal to use a function to do this. This function could then search for identifiers, and for each identifier it finds it could check if it's bound locally by checking if the variable occurs in the parameter list, in a `let`, `dolist` or similar construct.

An example of a package that similar things is [cwarn mode](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/cwarn.el), which highlight (among else) assignments inside expressions, for C-like languages.

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason that js2-mode can do tricks like identifying the scope of a variable is that, unlike other syntax highlighting modes, it actually [implements a complete JavaScript parser](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsteve-yegge.blogspot.com%2F2008%2F03%2Fjs2-mode-new-javascript-mode-for-emacs.html&ei=nxCVUbDQNsSSiAKEwICwCQ&usg=AFQjCNGyANwYIVJ0le0ZefmUaiwfLZbRhA&bvm=bv.46471029,d.cGE).  Reliably identifying Elisp globals would require a similarly non-trivial amount of code...

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller Emacs naturally includes a complete parser for Emacs Lisp, which is exposes by `syntax-ppss` and friends.  So at least the parsing work is already done for you.  Declared globals (i.e. by `defvar` and friends) can also easily identified by `special-variable-p`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `special-variable-p`. So it would certainly be possible to highlight declared variables.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that it is even impossible to accurately highlight variable binding scopes, or at least not without actually involving the byte compiler (or parts thereof), or re-implementing parts of Emacs Lisp' semantics.

The key problem are macros.  These are not hygienic in Emacs Lisp.  Thus **any**
macro can introduce **arbitrary local bindings**.  In fact, many macros do so, for instance `dolist`, `condition-case` and `pcase` from the standard library, or the anaphoric list processing functions from [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), to name a popular 3rd party library..

With these macros, it becomes **impossible** to determine the variable scoping from the syntactic context only.  Take the following example:

```
(condition-case err
    (--each my-fancy-list
      (my-fancy-function it nil t))
  (error (message "Error %S happened: %s" (car err) (cadr err))))
```

Without knowing about `condition-case` and `--each`, are `err` and `it` locally bound?  If so, in which sub-expressions are they bound, e.g. is `err` bound in all sub-expressions, or just the handler form only (the latter is the case)?

To determine variable scope in such cases, you either need to maintain an exhaustive whitelist of macros along with their binding properties, or you need to expand macros to determine their binding properties dynamically (e.g. look for `let` in the expanded body).

Both of these approaches amount to a lot of work when implemented, and have shortcomings.  A whitelist of macro definitions is almost naturally incomplete, incorrect and outdated (just look at the complex binding semantics of `pcase`), while expanding macros requires the macro definition to be present, which is not always the case, for instance if you are editing Emacs Lisp using the aforementioned dash.el, without having this library installed actually.

Still, expanding macros is probably the best effort, and even better, you don't need to implement it your own.  The Emacs Lisp byte compiler already does this, and it warns about references to free variables, and with lexical binding enabled also about unused lexical variables.  So, **byte compile** your files!

At best, avoid calling `byte-compile-file` from within your running Emacs, and instead write a `Makefile` to byte compile in a fresh Emacs instance, to have a clean environment:

```
SRCS = foo.el
OBJECTS = $(SRCS:.el=.elc)

.PHONY: compile
compile : $(OBJECTS)

%.elc : %.el
    $(EMACS) -Q --batch -f batch-byte-compile $<
```

In more complicated libraries, use the `-L` flag to Emacs to set up a proper
`load-path` for compilation.

Comment: Excellent points, thanks. My Emacs configuration is actually colouring `it` differently (using `font-lock-variable-face`), but I'm not sure which change lead to that. That's independent of context though. Looks like flycheck is the best option here.

Comment: @WilfredHughes This highlighting is installed by [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/1fc66790854e13ba3324041a29a383005b71b06a/dash.el#L927) itself.